# FileScanner with Array Object

Tags: java, arrays

Having a problem with my code. It compiles but I run into an issue of the Scanner printing null how many times which is due to the for-each loop at the end of the Driver class I put. The goal is to read from a text file for a first name, last name, and postal code strings and use a for-each loop to print out the input. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

A sample line of input file would read something like this:

> Firstname: Joe   Lastname: Jimbob  Postalcode: 55555

EDIT: There are 25 lines in the .txt file for an array that holds 25 Person Objects. My bad!

This is what I have so far simplified:

The Driver class to print out the data along with the Scanner:

```
... throws IO Exception

    String firstname = " ";
        String lastname = " ";
        String postalcode = " ";
        File file = new File("input.txt"); 
        Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(file);
        Person person[] = new Person[25]; // An array of 25 Person objects see Person class


        while(fileScan.hasNext()) //Error was generated here at Line 20 originally N. Pointer Exception not too sure how to regenerate it
        {
            String token= fileScan.next(); //Token to scan for each word and match it with the string before it
            if(token.equals("Firstname: "))
            {
                firstname = fileScan.next();
            }
            else if(token.equals("Lastname: "))
            {
                lastname = fileScan.next();
            }
            else if(token.equals("Postalcode: "))
            {
                postalcode = fileScan.next();
            }

            for(Person info : person)  // Generates null on execution supposed to print Array
            {
                System.out.println(info); // Prints null not exactly sure why 
            }
```

And the Person class to see where the Person Object is created:

```
public class Person
{
    private String firstname, lastname, postalcode;

    public Person(String firstname, String lastname, String postalcode)
    {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.postalcode = postalcode;

    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return(firstname + " " + lastname +" "+ postalcode);
    }
}
```

Comment: The key to asking questions about exceptions is that you really should show the exception stacktrace, and also you should indicate unambiguously which line throws it. Else we're forced to guess what may be wrong. Also you should do some debugging yourself to try to elucidate what could be wrong or where it could be coming from. That way you can be sure that the code you post is relevant to your problem.

Comment: I'll try and indicate that! Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You're also doing one `.hasNext()` check for 3 `.next()` lines. Myself, I'd check `.hasNextLine()` and call only one `.nextLine()` inside the loop, and then parse the line returned. My bet on your error -- you're not looking in the right place for the file. To check to see where Java is looking for your file, you could ask it. Place this code in your main method to find out: `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));`

Comment: You state, `throws IO Exception`, and then in your update you state, `Error was generated here at Line 20 originally N. Pointer Exception`. OK, now you're confusing me -- are you seeing an IOException or a NullPointException? Please be sure that your questions are as accurate and as complete as possible.

Comment: The folder location is actually correct! So it sees the file. I put the code in my main method and it returned the folder I have the .txt file in. I'll give parsing the nextline() a shot, I've done something similar before and it looks okay but it printing nulls from the for-each loop is a little confusing. I'll try and figure it out. Really appreciate it!

And that comment was really confusing my bad. I had a Null Point Exception previously, I didn't know how to regenerate it. I have no Pointer exceptions or anything like that, yet I get prints of null in the output.

Comment: @battleskies You're never adding a person the that `person` array. What else than `null` should it print?

Comment: @Tom: that should be an answer. Though I still suspect that he's cutting too many corners when truncating his code, so I am afraid that his code representation is not accurate.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That is true. Also `Oblivion Creations` already mentioned the problem with the `person` array :).

Comment: I'd be very keen to see a non-cut version of the method so we can actually work out whether it is the underlying problem or not. It'd also be interesting if he ends up with more than 25 people in the text file, but I suspect that is out of scope for the moment.

Comment: @Tom I think you're right. I never added them to the person array! Might be a silly question, but how would I add what I've scanned from a file to an array( in this case the Person array I created) not too sure how to go about doing that.

And I apologize, I tried to cut down to make it slightly easier to read and that might have made it more confusing. My bad. I really appreciate the help!

And in the .txt file, I have 25 lines to match the number of array objects. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the for loop AFTER you close the while loop. Something like:

```
while(fileScan.hasNext())
    {
        String token= fileScan.next();
        if(token.equals("Firstname: "))
        {
            firstname = fileScan.next();
        }
        else if(token.equals("Lastname: "))
        {
            lastname = fileScan.next();
        }
        else if(token.equals("Postalcode: "))
        {
            postalcode = fileScan.next();
        }
    }
    for(Person info : person)
    {
        System.out.println(info);
    }
```

This will still print nulls though, if you have less than 25 people in the file. You can also try:

```
    for(Person info : person)
    {
        if(info != null){
            System.out.println(info);
        }
    }
```

Edit:

JUST noticed it doesn't look like you are adding the people into the array? like

```
person[2] = new Person(firstName, lastname, postalcode); //etc
```

Comment: The Exception is an IOException, and so that makes your points, although valid, not likely to be the cause of his problems. I have to wonder how much of the issue that you see being due to his doing a poor job of trying to truncate his code.

Comment: Wow I totally didn't notice the comments in the code, just read his comment about 'printing nulls' and went from there.

Comment: @battleskies Don't forget to remove the space after each keywork (i.e. `"Firstname: "` and the others).